# separate the word contain letters and numbers into two parts

Tags: php, variables, cpu-word

How can I separate the word contain letters and numbers into two parts in the character variable and the number in the variable:

example:

```
<?
$x = "f25";
?>
```

I want to get the letter to a new variable $L="f";
and the number to another variable $N=25;

thanks alot

Comment: Please provide additional information: is it always 3 characters? always letter, number,number?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) without any lookarounds by passing the appropriate flags to `preg_split()`, like so:

```
$x = "f25";
list( $L, $N) = preg_split( '/([a-z]+)/i', $x, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump( $L, $N);
```

This [**will output**](http://viper-7.com/VWDNAq):

```
string(1) "f" string(2) "25"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[0-9])#i', "f25"));
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => f
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to regexp

```
$x = "f25";
list($L,$N) = sscanf($x,'%[A-Z]%d');
```